# MATLAB Histogram equalization on GIF images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram, color-mapping

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how to change a colormap of a grayscale GIF image after performing histogram equalization on the image. The process is perfectly simple with image compression types that don't have an associated colormap, such as JPEG, and I've gotten it to work with grayscale JPEG images.

```
clear
clc
[I,map] = imread('moon.gif');
h = zeros(256,1);    %array value holds number of pixels with same value
hmap = zeros(256,1);
P = zeros(256,1);    %probability that pixel intensity will appear in image
Pmap = zeros(256,1);
s = zeros(256,1);    %calculated CDF using P
smap = zeros(256,1);
M = size(I,1);
N = size(I,2);
I = double(I);

Inew = double(zeros(M,N));
mapnew = zeros(256,3);
for x = 1:M;
for y = 1:N;
for l = 1:256;
    %count pixel intensities and probability 
end
end
end

for j = 2:256
    for i = 2:j
        %calculate CDF of P
    end
end
s(1) = P(1);
smap(1) = Pmap(1);

for x = 1:M;
for y = 1:N;
for l = 1:256;
   %calculates adjusted CDF and sets it to new image
end
end
end
mapnew = mapnew/256;
Inew = uint8(Inew);
I = uint8(I);
subplot(1,2,1), imshow(Inew,map);     %comparing the difference between original map 
subplot(1,2,2), imshow(Inew,mapnew);  %to'enhanced' colormap, but both turn out poorly
```

All is fine in terms of the equalization of the actual image, but I'm not sure what to change about the color map. I tried performing the same operations on the colormap that I did with the image, but no dice.

Sorry that I can't post images cause of my low rep, but I'll try and provide all the info I can on request.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion: you can upload images on [imgur](http://imgur.com/) and post the links. A more privileged user can embed them into your question for you until you gain reputation to do that yourself... and welcome to SO!

Comment: if you have it working for regular images (grayscale or truecolor), you could always use `ind2gray` or `ind2rgb` to convert the image and its corresponding colormap into the first kind, and then perform your procedure. fwiw MATLAB already has `histeq` function that works on all kind of images

Comment: Thanks for the help y'all! The ind2gray function works like a charm. This was a class assignment so histeq was out of the question, save to make sure your code worked. I'll also keep in mind to use imgur for providing images. Again, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
function J=histeqo(I)

    J=I;
    [m,n]=size(I);
    [h,d]=imhist(I);
    ch=cumsum(h);  // The cumulative frequency
    imagesize=(m*n); // The image size lightsize=size(d,1);// The Lighting range
    tr=ch*(lightsize/imagesize); // Adjustment function

    for x=1:m
        for y=1:n
            J(x,y)=tr(I(x,y)+1);
        end
    end
    subplot(1,2,1);imshow(J);
    subplot(1,2,2);imhist(J);
end
```

Comment: welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. Please note that this is an English-speaking site. Can you please edit your answer to include English only comments?